# Bash errors: Unexpected EOF while looking for matching, Syntax error: Unexpected end of file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

I ran it through ShellCheck but could not understand what it wanted me to change,so here I am.

On opening terminal:

`bash: /home/helpabrother/.bashrc: line 118: unexpected EOF while looking for matching` "'

`bash: /home/helpabrother/.bashrc: line 121: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

I am also curious about what this line is doing.

```
'export PATH="echo export PATH="/home/mark/.local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc:$PATH" '
```

Bashfile:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
export PATHn:$PATH"

export PATH=/home/helpabrother/.local/bin:$PATHexport PATHn:$PATH"
export PATH="echo export PATH="/home/mark/.local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc:$PATH"  
export PATHn:$PATH"
```

Comment: Could you clarify which OS you’re running? 

Comment: Please do your `PATH` properly. That is not the right way. And you forgot quote marks. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/60219/1438484) for how to do it

Comment: Why are someone voting to close because it lacks clarity? It's pretty clear that the last 5 lines of the `~/.bashrc` file are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You changed your `.bashrc` file clearly without good knowledge of bash and perhaps even of what you really wanted to achieve. It is unlikely that a program made these clunky changes, unless it was malware. There are syntax errors. Line 118 has a lacking opening quote. Line 121 does a very strange thing, including sourcing in a file named `~/.bashrc:$PATH`.

Best advise unless you know very well what you want to achieve: restore your default bashrc:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Then you still can see what your needs are, and ask a specific question if unsure on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the last 5 lines starting with `export` in your `~/.bashrc` file (line 118-122 if I'm not mistaken) - it's a mess.

Then read up on how to properly set the `PATH` - the normal syntax is:

```
export PATH="/my/new/path:$PATH"
```

If you are in a situation where you need to do "nested"/"chained" load of your `~/.bashrc` (for instance if using screen or tmux), you can do a conditional path like this:

```
[[ $PATH != *"/my/new/path"* ]] && export PATH="/my/new/path:$PATH"
```

The above will ensure that `/my/new/path` will only be added if it's not already present.

And then do it the right way in your `~/.bashrc`